# Can I use lighten css property in ngStyle?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to use lighten property in ngStyle but it doesn't work.

I have color variable in component and I want to use it like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{color: schedule.group.color, background: 'lighten(' + schedule.group.color + ', 50%)'}">
```

Can someone gives some idea?

Comment: what is the value of `schedule.group.color`? you cannot use css functions inline. You could directly pass rgba value with 50% opacity (or implement lighten method in component to calculate correct opacity)

Comment: I have color  in hex. Yes I know this way to convert hex to rgb and add opacity value but I interest if there is any way to make this with hext

Comment: You cannot use sass mixins in template

Comment: @TemoKiknadze Like David says, you cannot use preprocessor functions (sass/less) inline. The only way is to use rgba. Or some ugly solutions, like creating different elements for text and background.

I would recommend to write a lighten function yourself in the component.

Comment: Yes I made with function. Thanks everyone

Comment: @TemoKiknadze, I change the function and the stackblitz a few

Comment: take a look to https://github.com/Qix-/color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thre're no "lighten" function in css -it is about less or Sass-. In internet there are javascripts function to make it, eg. [this in css.trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/)

**UPDATE** Important! (change the function)

```
  /**Credits to: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/ */
  //amt from 0 to 100
  lightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {

    amt=256-Math.floor(amt*5.12)
    const  usePound = col[0]=="#";
    if (usePound)
        col = col.slice(1);

    const num = parseInt(col,16);

    const rr=(num >> 16) + amt;
    const  bb = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
    const  gg = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;

    const r=rr>255?255:rr<0?0:rr;
    const b=bb>255?255:bb<0?0:bb;
    const g=gg>255?255:gg<0?0:gg;

    if ((g | (b << 8) | (r << 16))==0)
        return "#000000";

    return (usePound?"#":"") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);

  }
```

Use

```
<div [ngStyle]="{color: color, 'background-color': lightenDarkenColor(color, 10)}">hello word</div>
<div [ngStyle]="{color: color, 'background-color': lightenDarkenColor(color, 90)}">hello word</div>
```

see demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjf8hv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: NOTE: I change the function to values from 0 to 100 take account when the value pass of darkness (the old funcion return white, when must be return black

Comment: in https://github.com/Qix-/color there're a functions in javaScript to manipulate colors

Answer (score 0):

The above (answered) function sometimes return white and then I found that solution:

```
hexToRgbNew(hex: any, opacity: any): string {
    let h = hex.replace('#', '');
    h =  h.match(new RegExp('(.{' + h.length / 3 + '})', 'g'));

    for (let i = 0;  i < h.length; i++) {
        h[i] = parseInt(h[i].length === 1 ? h[i] + h[i] : h[i], 16);
    }

    if (typeof opacity !== 'undefined') { h.push(opacity); }

    return 'rgba(' + h.join(',') + ')';
}
```